# Insert into table matching records from two other tables taking an incredibly long time

Tags: mysql

I want to insert into a table matching records from two large, over 1M rows each, tables. I have a query prepared, however when I run it the query takes an extremely long time doing it. I run it and I have waited upwards to 45 minutes with no apparent results other than the table having taken some space while no records are showing.

This is the query I'm using:

```
INSERT INTO matching_books(isbn, qoh, qoo, price, discount, return) SELECT bn.* FROM books_new AS bn INNER JOIN books_old as bo on bn.isbn = bo.isbn where 1;
```

Can you please tell me if I have it right? I'm trying to run it also on HeidiSQL and the program suddenly froze.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: has books_old a index on bo.isbn ?

Comment: Yes, both tables have the same indexes

Comment: that also includes the field isbn ? can please post the result of **EXPLAIN SELECT bn.* FROM books_new AS bn INNER JOIN books_old as bo on bn.isbn = bo.isbn where 1**

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I did what you asked me to do and it resulted in no key being selected.

Comment: so you must create a index on COLUMN isbm in table books_old

Comment: Did just that and it worked like a charm. Thank you very much for helping me and sorry for the hassle.